# How to design when the type of a column in MySQL has changed its type? (used to be int, now needs to be int or string)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

We are developing database schemas in MySQL with evolving requirements.

It starts with a simple design:

`fact` table:

```
|id|featureid|featurevalue|
|----|----|----|
|1|1000|42|
```

`dimension` table:

```
|featureid|featurename|
|---------|-----------|
|1000|awesome_feature|
```

it all works fine until today, when a new requirement is needed to store a *string* for a `featurevalue` to the database.

i understand the basics of the schema of a table, and that the `featurevalue` column can NOT be both `bigint(20)` and `varchar(255)`.

So I am thinking something like adding a new column named `featurevalue_string` to the `fact` table.
However I'm not quite convinced by this solution, since there are only 1 or 2 features with string values, and the rest of should be still int.

The question here is, how to adopt to such change in the requirement in our database design?

Comment: You can still store those string featurevalue as int value in your DB. And store a mapping for them in your application code to display them as string, since they are 1 or 2 only

Comment: i simplified the question here. the actual string is a comma-separated list, and the actual number is a float. i don't see a way to use the approach to solve the problem.

Comment: Comma separated list ===> Normalize instead. Never use comma separated list in a column

Comment: EAV schema sucks.  Follow the tag I added to see why, and to see what little can be done about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can split it out into two columns:

```
FeatureDataType VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL 
FeatureData VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

The first one describes the data, the second contains the data.

Populate them as

```
FeatureDataType="INTEGER", FeatureData ="1234"
FeatureDataType="VARCHAR", FeatureData ="fire is hot"
```

Then when you SELECT the data, you can do a conversion to the data type specified in FeatureDataType.

Note that this is will actually become a maintenance and reporting problem and you probably should be re-working your schema and/or redefining your problem instead of doing this.